# Cannot share folders on G Suite Google Drive

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace-for-business, file-sharing, google-shared-drive

I just signed up for Google G Suite and created a company shared folder as instructed [by the G Suite Learning Center](https://gsuite.google.com/learning-center/products/drive/get-started-team-drive/#section-2-1). However for some reason I cannot share the folders with anyone as shown here:

[image: menu with share button disabled]

I'm 100% sure I got full share and access rights (after all I created those folders). Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the screenshot shows a background we could say that the folders are included in a "Shared Drive" (formerly "Team Drive"), also the link include in the question refers to a learning article about Team Drives.

Unfortunately, at this time it's not possible to share folders included in a Shared Drive but you could add the users you want to share the folder to the Shared Drive

Reference

- [How to enable folder sharing in Team Drives?](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps/NirpJ13VdJ4)